# Print queue content in order mutlithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, queue, locking

I would like to be able to read from a queue and print element that was in the queue in the same order that they pushed, for example:

(order is from left to right)
Queue -> [{1, "Single"},{2,"Single"}, {1,"Married"},{1,"Divorced"},{2,"Married"},{2,"Divorced"},{1,"Widow"},{2,"Widow"}]

My goal is to synchronized thread so in any case there are 2 threads running at PrintInOrder with argument {1, "Single"} at one thread and {1,"Married"} at second thread, it will print the {1,"Single"} before {1,"Married"} because it first in the queue.

I try to solve it by the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class PrintUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var printUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded =
                new PrintUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded();
            printUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded.PopulateQueue();
            printUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded.ReadFromQueue();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private Dictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim> userLocks;
        private Queue<User> usersQueue;

        private string[] maritalStatus = { "Married", "Divorced", "Widow" };

        public PrintUsersQueueInOrderMutlithreaded()
        {
            usersQueue = new Queue<User>();
            userLocks = new Dictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim>();
        }

        internal void PopulateQueue()
        {
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 1, MaritalStatus = "Single" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 2, MaritalStatus = "Single" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 1, MaritalStatus = "Married" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 1, MaritalStatus = "Divorced" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 2, MaritalStatus = "Married" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 2, MaritalStatus = "Divorced" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 1, MaritalStatus = "Widow" });
            usersQueue.Enqueue(new User() { Id = 2, MaritalStatus = "Widow" });
        }

        internal void ReadFromQueue()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            while (usersQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var user = usersQueue.Dequeue();
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => PrintInOrder(user)));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private void PrintInOrder(User user)
        {
            SemaphoreSlim userLock;
            lock (userLocks)
            {
                if (!userLocks.ContainsKey(user.Id))
                {
                    userLocks[user.Id] = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
                }
                userLock = userLocks[user.Id];
            }

            userLock.Wait();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);
            }
            finally
            {
                userLock.Release();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Thread id {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,2}" +
                $" User id {Id,2} Marital status {MaritalStatus,2}";
        }
    }
}
```

It make we wonder if it possible to control the order of `PrintInOrder` execution :\

Thanks!

Comment: It makes me wonder what question you're asking? It also makes me wonder what's wrong with your current code.

Comment: The question is if it possible to keep the order of the queue in each thread per user, for example, thread 1 will print user 1 in the order Single , Married, Divorced and Widow.

Comment: Could you edit the question and clarify what part is given and unchangeable, and what is subject to potential modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you do `Task.Run`, you're making the order indeterminate by creating multiple parallel flows - you *cannot* recover from that; if you want to preserve order, you need to *retain* order. Actually, though, your code is already broken re thread-safety: you have concurrent access to `usersQueue` which is *not* a thread-safe object. If this was me, I would switch to something like a `Channel<User>`, and have one reader that simply dequeues from that (asynchronously, or even via `await foreach` on the `.AsAsyncEnumerable()` from it), and have that single reader to all the writes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
In other words, if the queue is given and I couldn't have access to it  and I do have access only to PrintInOrder method, is it impossible to print all users in the same order they was in the queue?

Comment: @LiorDadon the only way to do that is to have a single worker doing the printing; otherwise they are all just racing, and anyone can win

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the goal here is that users with the same id should maintain order, but order is not necessary maintained for users with different Ids.

The by far simplest solution would just be to just print all users synchronously. The console is inherently synchronous anyway, so the whole thing with creating tasks is pointless if all you are doing is printing items. I.e. just do:

```
while (usersQueue.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(usersQueue.Dequeue());
}
```

But lets assume you want to do some significant processing of users instead of just printing. So you would actually get some benefit from some amount of parallel processing.

The general approach is to queues, to ensure some items are processed in order, while allowing others to be processed concurrently. There are several possible ways to do this:

1. Create ConcurrentQueues yourself, and tasks looping thru each queue.
2. Use [dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) to create a pipeline. You could use filters and concurrency limits to configure the pipeline however you want.
3. Use a [LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler](https://gist.github.com/andersonimes/2572113) per user Id, with a limit of one, when starting tasks.